# Enter key is "clicking" the wrong button. asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have two asp buttons and a asp textbox. One button is to logout and the other to add the content of the textbox (username) to a database table.

All works great except when I type in a username and hit the enter key, it logs me off i.e. clicks logout button.

```
<asp:Button style="float: right;" ID="logout" runat="server" Text="LogOut" /> 
<asp:Label AssociatedControlID="adduser" Text="Add new admin user." runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="adduser" runat="server" placeholder="Enter username here"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="adduserbtn" runat="server" Text="Add" />
```

I got it to work by wrapping the textbox and adduserbtn button in a panel and setting the adduserbtn button as the default button.

```
<asp:Button style="float: right;" ID="logout" runat="server" Text="LogOut" /> 
<asp:Panel DefaultButton="adduserbtn" runat="server" ID="addUserPanel">
    <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="adduser" Text="Add new admin user." runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="adduser" runat="server" placeholder="Enter username here" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="adduserbtn" runat="server" Text="Add" />
</asp:Panel>
```

But this feels more like a "hack" than a fix.  Does anybody know of a better / cleaner way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Panel with DefaultButton is a recommended approach in ASP.NET Web Form, since we can only have one ***form*** tag in a page

Comment: By default the browser will bind the enter key to the first input / button it finds. Just restructure and place the addUserBtn button as the first element and use css to place your element as you wish. Or use DefaultButton as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ever your are done is correct. This not a hack this the feature ASP.Net.
Just change the code as folllowing

```
<asp:Panel DefaultButton="adduserbtn" runat="server" ID="addUserPanel">
    <asp:Button Style="float: right;" ID="logout" runat="server" Text="LogOut" />
    <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="adduser" Text="Add new admin user." runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="adduser" runat="server" placeholder="Enter username here"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="adduserbtn" runat="server" Text="Add" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Thanks VDWWD for formatting it. I am new to this. Little struggling. Thanks once again for formatting this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Partha Thakura with the Panel and the `DefaultButton` is correct and can be used when you want a button pressed. But you can also disable the clicking of the Enter Key with javascript. I use this in large forms because pressing Enter will trigger all the Validators or do the form post with more input fields to go.

```
<div onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</div>
```

Just make sure you don't use it on a MultiLine TextBox (textarea).

Comment: this doesnt work for me. The event doesnt even fire if the focus is someplace else.